# How to use the verb 'offend'

Tags: sentence-meaning

> 1. This can make other people feel offended
> 2. This can make other people offended
> 3. This can offend other people.

These are exactly the same meaning without any difference in nuance, right?

Comment: no, IMO the first one **may be** considered as 'guessing'. The other two are 'statements'! :)

Comment: Yes, these all have the exact same meaning.

Comment: The first feels slightly softer and every so slightly more poilite, but they all mean the same thing to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** I don't detect any difference in meaning.

A different form may flow better with the surrounding text, but you'll be saying the same thing.

The first one *might* be *slightly* softer since it refers to people *feeling* offended, rather than *being* offended, but this is a basically meaningless distinction.